# $u$ is harmonic and $v = \phi(u)$. Prove $v$ is subharmonic.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Problem Statement:
$\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth and convex. Assume $u$ is harmonic and $v = \phi(u)$. Prove $v$ is subharmonic.

My attempt at a following solution is below:

We hope to show that $\Delta \phi(u) \geq 0$. We have:
\begin{equation}
        \Delta\phi(u) = \sum_{i=1}^n\phi'(u)\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2} = \phi'(u)\Delta u = 0
    \end{equation}

So we can atually conclude that $\phi(u)$ is harmonic. This this correct? It seems too simple to be true.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Aren't there any second derivatives of $\phi$?

Comment: It's not right. Try this with $n=1$, and $u(x) = x$ (which is harmonic). Your argument (were it right) would imply that every twice-differentiable function $\phi$ is harmonic.

Comment: This follows from the definition (in terms of means over spheres) by Jensen's inequality for convex functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi$ is convex, one has $\phi''(s)\ge0$. In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta\phi(u) &=& \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial \phi(u)}{\partial x_i} \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\phi'(u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^n\bigg[\frac{\partial \phi'(u)}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} +\phi'(u)\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2} \bigg]\\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^n\bigg[\phi''(u)\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right)^2 +\phi'(u)\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2} \bigg]\\
&=& \phi''(u)\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right)^2 +\phi'(u)\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}\\
&=&\phi''(u)\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right)^2 \\
&\ge&0
\end{eqnarray}
which means that $\phi(u)$ is subharmonic.